# Error while installing matplotlib using pip install

Tags: python, matplotlib, pip

I installed python, jupyter notebook, numpy and pandas using pip instll on the office system without any problem but am unable to install Matplotlib. I get the following error:

pip install matplotlib

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1123)'))': /simple/matplotlib/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1123)'))': /simple/matplotlib/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1123)'))': /simple/matplotlib/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1123)'))': /simple/matplotlib/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1123)'))': /simple/matplotlib/
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/matplotlib/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/matplotlib/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1123)'))) - skipping
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement matplotlib
ERROR: No matching distribution found for matplotlib
```

I also tried :

```
python -m pip install -U pip
python -m pip install -U matplotlib
```

And:

```
!{sys.executable} -m pip install matplotlib
```

raise error:

```
!{sys.executable} -m pip install matplotlib '!{sys.executable}' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file
```

I don't know what the problem is or how to fix it, please help me out.
.     .

Comment: Which python version are you using?

Comment: did you  imported sys?:  import sys